# Can I get actual grunt process from Start-Process, not CMD process?

Tags: node.js, powershell

I'm using

```
Start-Process grunt -ArgumentList 'serve' -PassThru
```

and add it to an `ArrayList`. When I view said `ArrayList` it shows `cmd` process, not actual `node.js` process that was launched. If I try to `Stop-Process` it, quite obviously, kills `cmd` process, not the running `grunt`. I can locate running `grunt` with `Get-Process node`.

The problem is I need multiple grunts running at the same time and I want a way to distinguish between them somehow. Is there any way I can get actual `node` process into PowerShell upon initializing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `grunt` is launched via `grunt.cmd` which is run by `CMD`.  This file launches `grunt` in `node`.

Here is an example of how to find notepad2.exe launched from a CMD similarly to your example:

```
# start a CMD which starts notepad2 and then waits on it
$process = Start-Process -PassThru 'cmd.exe'  '/c "C:\Program Files\Notepad2\Notepad2.exe"'

# Wait for notepad2 to be launched
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# find the children of CMD, and kill the one which is notepad2
(Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ParentProcessId='$($process.Id)' AND Name = 'Notepad2.exe'")  | %{ Stop-Process  -Id $_.ProcessId}
```

Translating this for grunt:

```
# start Grunt via grunt.cmd
$process = Start-Process grunt -ArgumentList 'serve' -PassThru

# Wait for node to be launched
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# find the children of CMD, and kill the one which is node
(Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ParentProcessId='$($process.Id)' AND Name = 'node.exe'")  | %{ Stop-Process  -Id $_.ProcessId}
```

Comment: Any reason why you use both `-Filter` and `Where-Object`? Both can be merged in one `-Filter` (WMI is using "Name" for that property though): `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId = $($process.Id) and Name = 'notepad.exe'"`

Comment: Pure laziness in figuring out the syntax and at least some of the query has to be in the cim filter for efficiency

Comment: I update the `-Filter` and eliminated the `Where-Object` per @BartekB `s comment.

Answer (score 1):

`grunt` isn't a Win32 executable, it's a javascript file that's run by `node.exe`.  The easiest way to get the instance of node that's running grunt would be to start it yourself:

```
$ps = start-process -passthru  node -argumentlist "$env:APPDATA\npm\node_modules\grunt\bin\grunt"
```

Comment: The problem is I need to launch local `grunt serve`  from project folder. There is only `gruntfile.js` in the folder. Feeding it to `node` through `-ArgumentList` doesn't do the trick.